# Displaying the name in jsp page when selecting from a drop-down list

Tags: java, jsp, dao

In my `jsp` file, I have a drop-down list which print out the case name from the database using `<s:iterator>`.

When I click on a case name, it will direct to another jsp page. On that jsp page, I wish to print out the name of the case. How do I get the name from `DAO` file and pass it to the `jsp` page?

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery and manually redirect the page with a query string app

you can redirect a page by using `$("#formid").submit();`

Answer (score 0):

If you managed the *link* to the new page, you could always pass alomg some parameters. Like `?title=NamOfYourSelection`

This you can easiliy access on target jsp.